# Attempting Simultaneous File Operations

Tags: c#, powershell, sql-server-2008-r2, asp.net-4.0, powershell-2.0

I am attempting to create an ASP.NET 4.0 website (C#) that does the following: after the user clicks a button, take user inputs (from text boxes) and call a Powershell script on the server.  The Powershell script output is logged to a textfile on the same machine.  The script executes some stored procedures on a SQL server.  Once the script is done executing, the page reads the contents of the log file and returns them in the page.  The reason I log this as I do is because I need to capture the "verbose" output of these operations.

The problem I am having is that the whole set of commands that are run after the user clicks the button is queued if another user has the site open and is attempting the same operation.  I am not clear as to why this happens.  When run outside of the website, the Powershell scripts execute in parallel.  The log files that the application writes to use a timestamp and user inputted information to ensure that they are different depending on who is inputting the info.

Here is the code that is executed when the button is clicked:

```
protected void Test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        // Get the current date/time to use a timestamp for the log file
        DateTime curDate = DateTime.Now;
        string logFileName = "D:\\test1\\logs\\" + curDate.Year + curDate.Month + curDate.Day +
            curDate.Hour + curDate.Minute + curDate.Second + curDate.Millisecond + "_" +
            TextBox1.Text.Replace("\\", "_") + "_Test.txt";

        // Clean the Result TextBox
        ResultBox.Text = string.Empty;

        // Initialize PowerShell engine
        var shell = PowerShell.Create();

        // Add a script to the PowerShell shell object that will execute the instructions with the given input
        shell.Commands.AddScript("powershell.exe -file D:\\test1\\ps_script0.ps1 '" + TextBox3.Text + "' '" +
            TextBox1.Text + "' '" + TextBox2.Text + "' '" + TextBox4.Text + "' > " + logFileName);

        // Execute the script
        shell.Invoke();

        // Create a StreamReader object to read the results of the script instructions and then store the file's contents in a string
        StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(logFileName);
        String results = sr.ReadToEnd();
        results = results.Replace("VERBOSE: ", "");
        sr.Close();

        // Set the text of the result box to the string that was read in
        ResultBox.Text = results;
    }
```

I am hoping to find out if there is information I can read about allowing multiple users to click this button, and have the backend script run simultaneously for each of them.  I looked into asynchronous pages and threads, but I don't think this is necessary in my case since each user's page should have its own thread.  Any help here is much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I would like to know the answer to this as well.  I have a similar thing on one of my ASP.NET pages, but it's so small and so few users that I've never noticed, but now I'm wondering if mine is also not running concurrently.

Comment: You probably want to re-evaluate what you're attempting to do. Having a webpage execute a script from an ASP .NET process is potentially very dangerous.

Comment: In my case it's for an intranet site used between employees.  Specifically it's just like the above, except the script itself is necessary to query ESX servers to find out what virtual machines are at what IP addresses.  If there's another way way to pull that off online via an intranet site, I'm all ears.

Comment: Is there blocking in the database perhaps?  Run a sp_who while it is blocking and see if there are any non-0 values in the blk column.

Comment: @CptSupermrkt It would probably make a lot more sense to write an application that periodically polls the data you want to expose via the web and stores it (in a database or an XML file or even in-memory as a WCF service), and then have your webpage query that data.

Comment: I have the same situation as @CptSupermrkt...this is an intranet site only used between employees.  I am not concerned about security.  My goal is to create an interface into running specific SQL Server commands on a given instance without giving the user sysadmin (the rights are built into the website and the commands that can be run are hardcoded).  If there is another way to do this then I am open to suggestions.